# tried gem update --system 2.1.9 mistakenly now gem doesn't work

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I mistakenly tried to do `gem update --system 2.1.9` when I have ruby version `1.9.3-p194`.  I get the following error (below) any time I try to use gem from the command-line. I'm trying to figure out how to undo the damage but I can't find where rubygems is setting the **GEM_PATH**.

```
/Users/jgalt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb:53:in  `alias_method': undefined method `default_system_source_cache_dir' for class `Module' (NameError)
from /Users/jgalt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb:53:in `block in deprecate'
from /Users/jgalt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb:51:in `class_eval'
from /Users/jgalt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb:51:in `deprecate'
from /Users/jgalt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1298:in `singletonclass'
from /Users/jgalt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1285:in `<module:Gem>'
from /Users/jgalt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1284:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

Comment: I see you have used rvm, you can reinstall ruby with rvm command `rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p194` , or could you wish to repair system without reinstallation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to just install rubygems you can use:

```
rvm rubygems latest
```

or if you wish latest version for a series:

```
rvm rubygems latest-2.1
```

or if you wish specific version:

```
rvm rubygems 2.1.9
```